# Is there an easy way to integrate QuickCheck (Quiviq) with Erlang Eunit and if so how?

Tags: testing, functional-programming, automated-tests, erlang, quickcheck

Whenever I have tried to use Quiviq I am not able to run it within the `eunit:test/2`. Is there a way to do so, such that you can get the Eunit report, but also showing in detail if the Quiviq fails and how many of the Quiviq for each individual Quiviq test-case, that fails.

Comment: A solution that comes to mind is wrapping the property in an eunit test, like `my_test() -> ?assert(eqc:quickcheck(...)).` Does that do what you want?